# Does the Shaliach Tzibur for Maariv need to wait for a minyan?

Tags: halacha, tefillah-betzibbur

Does the Shaliach Tzibur for Maariv need to wait for 10 people to start Shemona Esrei (including him)?

Comment: Why might Maariv be different than any other prayer regarding how many people should be starting the Amida together, whether ideally or bedieved?

Comment: Welcome Efraim: Thanks for bringing your question here.

Answer (score 3):

According to the following authorities - Rav Ovadia Yosef in Yechave Daas 7, [Minchas Yitzchak 9:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1601&st=&pgnum=16), Shaivet Halevi 11:20, Bais Baruch 19:3, and B’tzel Hachachma 9:135 a chazan can start Shemona Esrei with a total of six people out of the 10. Although there are authorities that disagree one who starts with six has who to rely on.

I have heard this question asked to a Rav who responded that the person who is Davening with a Minyan should do his utmost to hold by the Amida with the Chazan.

Comment: What does "hold by the Amida with the Chazan" mean please?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok: He should be ready to start the silent Shemona Esrei when the Chazan is ready and not make the Chazan wait for him.